# Return a local C-string for function with C++ string return value

Tags: c++, string

The following piece of code compiles and runs without errors and with the expected output:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string getString()
{
    char s[] = "Hello world!";
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    cout << getString() << endl;
}
```

My question is, will this always work? Ordinarily if you return a C-string that was declared locally you can run into some undefined behavior, but in this case is that still a problem since it is run through the string constructor and (presumably) copied into dynamic memory?

Comment: One of the main reason `std::string` added to standard library - it can be used as an embedded type like `int` and `double`, so yes it is fine to return `std::string` by value.

Comment: Did you know that string litterals have static storage duration: [cpp-ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). So if your c-string just point to a string literral like in `const char* s="Hello World"` you can safely return it from your function, since s is a pointer to an object with static storage duration. This is why `std::except::what()` or `type_info::name()` return a c-string

Comment: @Oliv that's a neat fact but this is just an example, in my real program the C string is created at runtime

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 return s;
```

That line is equivalent to:

```
return std::string(s);
```

And that will make a *copy* of the string, so it's fine.

**reference:** http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string (constructor #5)

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s.

**Edit:** One more detail. You mention

> copied into dynamic memory?

And the answer is maybe, perhaps, it doesn't really matter.

The semantics provided by `std::string` make no specification towards this, it just guarantees that it can be copied/moved around and accessed in a consistent matter. How it acheives this is up to the library implementor.

In fact, popular implementations of `std::string` use something called the "**S**mall **S**tring **O**ptimization". Where strings under a certain length are stored within the string object itself.

Comment: The temporary `std::string` object that is returned is constructed (not copied!) from the array `s`.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting, the constructor of `std::string` copies the content of the string pointed by `s`. `s` is still a string, a c string, but a string nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. There's no denying that "a _copy_ of the string" is made, in the sense that the string's bytes will be copied.